# App crashes on IOS 6 - UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller

My app was working just fine until I updated to Xcode 4.5 and I ran it on IOS 6.
Now it crashes with the exception - 
UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency - A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time.

Does any one have an idea why and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using a UITabBarController?

Answer (score 10):

Well I fixed that problem - Apparently you need to remove the UIViewController in the XIB file, and leave only the view.

Comment: This problem was terribly annoying to figure out, thanks for the one-sentence fix. It worked.

Comment: Plus One for you sir! This was the exact issue I had.

Comment: Anybody know WHY this is necessary?