# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency crashes app only in iOS 8 and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

i have an app which work fine in iOS 7 and Xcode 5. As soon as I updated it to iOS 8 and Xcode 6 it crashes when app try to slide up UIDatePicker in the view when a textField is tapped. 
I am using storyboard.
Anybody has idea why?

i have read upon this but its for Xib.

[App crashes on IOS 6 - UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641833/app-crashes-on-ios-6-uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency)

please help 
thanks

my code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    //set picker color start
    [self.myDatePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];


    //set picker color finish
    //calculate bounds start
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    //calculate bounds finish
    //calculate the fraction between the top and bottom of the middle section for the text field's midline start
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
    //calculate the fraction between the top and bottom of the middle section for the text field's midline finish
    //Clamp this fraction so that the top section is all "0.0" and the bottom section is all "1.0 start
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }
    //Clamp this fraction so that the top section is all "0.0" and the bottom section is all "1.0 finish
    /*start
     Now take this fraction and convert it into an amount to scroll by multiplying by the keyboard height for the current screen orientation. Notice the calls to floor so that we only scroll by whole pixel amounts */
     UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
     if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
     orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
     {
     animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
     }
     else
     {
     animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
     }
     //finish
    //Finally, apply the animation start
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myDatePicker];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
    //Finally, apply the animation finish
    //Animate back again start
```

my crash log

```
2014-09-14 13:12:52.930 Pay 2014-15 free[2191:83060]
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', 
reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7be0a570> should have parent view controller:<AddHoursViewController: 0x7c38e800> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7c238a00>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02101df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d8ba97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02101d1d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   UIKit                               0x008cff9c -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 210
    4   UIKit                               0x00f4b44d -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 576
    5   UIKit                               0x00f4c1be __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke + 103
    6   UIKit                               0x007f73bf +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    7   UIKit                               0x00f4bf9c -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 374
    8   UIKit                               0x00ce9101 __64-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:]_block_invoke1459 + 43
    9   UIKit                               0x00f473af -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 56
    10  UIKit                               0x00ce9006 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1242
    11  UIKit                               0x00ce91df -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animated:] + 73
    12  UIKit                               0x00ce922b -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:] + 68
    13  UIKit                               0x00ce1478 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1803
    14  UIKit                               0x0092be95 -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 316
    15  UIKit                               0x0092b1dc -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 562
    16  UIKit                               0x007f1de0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
    17  UIKit                               0x00fb7ffb -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
    18  UIKit                               0x00bbde8f -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 200
    19  UIKit                               0x00bc04b6 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2762
    20  UIKit                               0x00bb3d27 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 327
    21  UIKit                               0x00bb25a4 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 561
    22  UIKit                               0x00bb45ed -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    23  UIKit                               0x00bb7f6a ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 57
    24  UIKit                               0x00bb7e2d _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    25  UIKit                               0x00babd36 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 3720
    26  UIKit                               0x007c771b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
    27  UIKit                               0x007c857f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
    28  UIKit                               0x0078daa9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    29  UIKit                               0x0079d8de _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    30  UIKit                               0x00772079 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x020257bf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0201b2cd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0201a828 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0201a1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x02019fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x0394624f GSEventRunModal + 192
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x0394608c GSEventRun + 104
    38  UIKit                               0x00775e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    39  Pay 2014-15 free                    0x0014ed7d main + 141
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x0736cac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) `enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: code added by editing the question. please have a look at it. UIDatePicker is added in storyboard and connected to a property @Property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet *mypickerVirw; If I remove connection system Keyboard come up, no crash. I have tried [textField resignFirstResponder]; It does stop keyboard coming up but UIDatePickerView does not come up and app crashes.

Comment: Same here! any news?

Comment: I have some news:
Im using this code: self.UITextFieldValue.inputView = self.UIDatePickerBirthday;

Do you have this too? i guess it is this what causes the crash

Comment: I really push UIDatePicker up in scrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
                {
    //init and allocate(my problem was addind nil object into view.         
    self.myDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

    [self.myDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];

    //to get text off picker
    [self.myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //to hide picker
    _tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = self.myDatePicker.date;
    //or select pickerViewMode

    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 1: //pulls selected text into textField
            self.textField1.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        break;
     }
}

-(void)hideKeyboard {
    //NSLog(@"6  hideKeyboard");
    [self.textField1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Code says "my problem was addind nil object into view", so I guess that's the explanation. Doesn't help me, but at least it's solution to his problem. Continuing my studies...

Answer (score 3):

Either you create date picker programatically or if you are using it as a dragged in component do the below given steps

1.Create Programatically

```
 datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
//NSString *maxDateString = @"01-Jan-2012";
NSString *theMinimumDate = @"01-Jan-1976";
// the date formatter used to convert string to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// the specific format to use
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
// converting string to date
NSDate *theMaximumDate = [NSDate date];//[dateFormatter dateFromString: maxDateString];
NSDate *theminimumDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: theMinimumDate];

// repeat the same logic for theMinimumDate if needed
// here you can assign the max and min dates to your datePicker
[datePicker setMaximumDate:theMaximumDate];//the max age restriction (if needed, or else dont use this line)
[datePicker setMinimumDate:theminimumDate]; //the min age restriction

// set the mode
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// and finally set the datePicker as the input mode of your textfield
[Textfield setInputView:datePicker];
```

2.From Xib

```
[self.DatePickerView removeFromSuperview];
[Textfield setInputView:self.DatePickerView];
[Textfield setInputView:self.DatePickerView];
```

Answer (score 1):

date picker should not be child of any super view

**Problem**:

You have to ensure that the view you will assign to inputView or inputAccessoryView don't belong to any parent view. Maybe when you create these views from xib inside a ViewController, by default they are subviews of a superview.

**Solution Tips**:

Using method removeFromSuperview for the view you will assign to inputView or inputAccessoryView

see detail in this link

[Error when adding input view to textfield iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8][1])

Answer (score 0):

The base problem was likely caused by adding the date picker as a child view of the view controllers view.

Removing the following line would have prevented this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myDatePicker];
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25831317/1871400

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to ensure all the inputAccessoryView do not belong to any parent view.
Refer: [Error when adding input view to textfield iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8).