# removeFromSuperview ios crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

My app crashes, not always, at the following method

```
// overridden
- (void)dismiss
{

    [super dismiss]; 
    [containerView_ removeFromSuperview];
    containerView_ = nil;
}
```

crash happens at removerFromSuperview.

There is a "show" method as well

```
// overridden
- (void)show
{

    if (self.parentView == nil)
    {
        // No parentView, create transparent view as parent
        CGSize  frameSize = [UIApplication currentSize];
        containerView_ = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.height, frameSize.width)];


        containerView_.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        containerView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.parentView = containerView_;

        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {

            if(some condition )
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:containerView_];
            else
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:containerView_];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:containerView_];
        }
    }

    [super show];

    // This is done to allow the Cancel button to be pressed but nothing else - do after [super show]!
    self.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

It is strange, that code used to work. I am trying to compile the app for arm64, but I don't understand how that modification impacted those methods.

My app is a non-ARC app, and I cannot go to ARC right now.

Any ideas?

Comment: the issue is due to child - parent views, this code works well in iOS 6-7 but not in iOS 8, you would have to check the parent views of the child views and views hierarchy. App crashes when you try to remove and sometimes when you add a child view.

Comment: Getting any error log ?

Comment: Check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865391/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-crashes-app-only-in-ios-8-and-xcode-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to dismiss view like this.

// overridden

```
- (void)dismiss
{
   if(containerView_)
    [containerView_ removeFromSuperview];

   containerView_ = nil;
   [super dismiss]; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was by mistake edit your answer , I don't know how to undo

Comment: why the containerView_ = nil is outside the if(containerView_)?

Comment: it will not affect your source code because here I am only assign nil to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code -

```
- (void)dismiss
{
  if (containerView_)
  {
    [containerView_ removeFromSuperview];
    containerView_ = nil;
    [super dismiss]; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if container view have superview

```
- (void)dismiss
{
  if ([containerView_ superview])
  {
    [containerView_ removeFromSuperview];
    containerView_ = nil;
    [super dismiss]; 
  }
}
```